# How to kill nodejs script from console. If i use while cycle - linuxmint

Tags: node.js, gnome-terminal

How to kill nodejs from console. If I use while(true) cycle. What i need to add in my script to kill Ctrl+c My os is linux mint. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: @MatteoVioletto I use GNOME Terminal

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18594